# Brand new to coding - added a button how to add random number

Tags: ios, swift

Im brand new to learning coding and I have just started teaching myself swift this week. I've made a button on my screen and want it to display a random number between 1-100 when pressed. Can anyone assist? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check out [ask]. In this case, it's unclear how you've added the button, because you haven't included any code. UIKit? SwiftUI? It's also unclear where you want to display it -- console? In a text view on the screen? There are plenty of examples of generating a random number in Swift, so that should be easily findable. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random Int between 1 and 100 by

```
Int.random(in: 1..<101)
```

But please add more info to your question